# Setting up firebase Admin SDK in node

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, reset-password

I am developing a password-recovery block for my application. I found out that I could call `sendPasswordResetEmail` function which works fine, but I want to use my own email template so I need to use Admin SDK and call `admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(email)` to generate a link where I could extract the OobCode to use resetPassword function. But for some reason I got the following error calling `admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(email)`:

> errorInfo: {
> code: 'auth/insufficient-permission',
> message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property has insufficient permission to access the requested resource.
> },
> codePrefix: 'auth'
> }

The permissions settting should be fine in firebase, altough I am totaly new in firebase.

Here is my code what includes the firebase-client initialization, admin sdk initialization, the post request:

```
import config from "config"
const serviceAccount = config.get('serviceAccount')
import admin from "firebase-admin";
const dbUrl = ""

try {
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        databaseURL: dbUrl
  });
} catch (e) {
console.log(e)
}

export {admin}

//------------------------------------------------

import { admin } from './firebase/firAdmin.js';
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth";
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';

 const {
  FIR_APP_ID,
  FIR_API_KEY,
  FIR_PROJECT_ID,
  FIR_DATBASE_URL,
  FIR_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  FIR_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  FIR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
} = process.env

const firConfig = {
  appId:              FIR_APP_ID,
  apiKey:             FIR_API_KEY,
  authDomain:         FIR_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL:        FIR_DATBASE_URL,
  projectId:          FIR_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket:      FIR_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId:  FIR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
}
const firApp = initializeApp(firConfig)

//------------------------------------------------

app.post('/password-recovery', async(req, res) => {
  const {email} = req.body;
  admin.auth().generatePasswordResetLink(email).then((link) => {
    console.log(link)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

Comment: Your service account could be missing a Firebase specific IAM role. Did you generate the service account key from the Firebase Console (not the GCP console)?
See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk

Comment: Yes I generated that. Basically I got a service account key for whole different project from my employer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wanted to highlight here that service account keys could be a security risk if not managed properly. Make sure you keep your service account key safe and do not upload the key with your code. If you deploy your apps on Google environments use ADC by initializing the SDK without SA credentials. Ex: `const app = initializeApp();`